# g++ internal compiler error segmentation fault with recursive constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++14

I recently updated my g++ version to 6.3.0 (g++ (Homebrew GCC 6.3.0) 6.3.0), but now i get `g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11 (program cc1plus)`.
With the previous version (I'm not completely sure but around) 5.2 everything worked. And on one of my other computers I use g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 and that also works.

The code is:

```
constexpr bool checkForPrimeNumber(const int p, const int t)
{
    return p <= t or (p % t and checkForPrimeNumber(p, t + 2));
}

constexpr bool checkForPrimeNumber(const int p)
{
    return p == 2 or (p & 1 and checkForPrimeNumber(p, 3));
}

int main() 
{
    static_assert(checkForPrimeNumber(65521), "bug...");
}
```

I compile the code with

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -fconstexpr-depth=65535
```

What can i possibly do to work around this?

**EDIT:**

Bug report [sumitted](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78907)

Comment: "internal compiler error" - is a near-automatic bug in the compiler, and should be filed as such. Using clang on your platform (it is a Mac, right?), the static assert fires out of the box with the proper reason: a constexpr eval recursive depth to 512. If g++ is intending on doing the same, I would think it would be more robust than spewing an internal compiler error and a seg-fault.

Comment: @WhozCraig Both clang and g++ have a recursive limit of 512. That is why I use `-fconstexpr-depth=65535`. With clang (Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)) I get `clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: Lolz, well, you gave me a new, predictable way to crash Xcode; thanks for that =P. Neither of those should crash, and both are bugs to the vendor imho.

Comment: As a workaround: Have you tried to write an iterative version of that (requires c++14)?

Comment: @downvoter Whats is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from a stack overflow internally in g++. I was allegedly able to increase the stack (on macOS 10.11.6). However, it did not resolve the issue at hand.
I came up with another solution, to split the check into two branches, here is the code:

```
constexpr bool checkForPrimeNumber(const int p, const int t, const int hi)
{
    return p < hi and (p <= t or (p % t and checkForPrimeNumber(p, t + 2, hi)));
}

constexpr bool checkForPrimeNumber(const int p)
{
    return p == 2 or (p & 1 and (checkForPrimeNumber(p, 3, 32768) or checkForPrimeNumber(p, 3+32768, 65536)));
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(checkForPrimeNumber(65521), "");
}
```

Thanks

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments a solution may be to use C++14:

```
constexpr bool checkForPrimeNumber(const int p)
{
    if (p < 2)
        return false;
    if (p == 2)
        return true;
    if (~p & 1)
        return false;
    for (int i = 3; i < p; i += 2)
    {
        if (p % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```